# How can I now make a my GUI to output the results?

Tags: python, user-interface, connection, tkinter

I'm studying `Tkinter`, and I need a Button, and then when I click it, do something with some code, and then print the result.

I started with this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import heapq

root = Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")


#-------------------CODE-----------------------
def makeHuffTree(symbolTupleList):
   trees = list(symbolTupleList)

   heapq.heapify(trees)
   while len(trees) > 1:
      childR, childL = heapq.heappop(trees), heapq.heappop(trees)
      parent = (childL[0] + childR[0], childL, childR)
      heapq.heappush(trees, parent)
   return trees[0]

def printHuffTree(huffTree, prefix = ''):
   if len(huffTree) == 2:
      print huffTree[1], prefix
   else:
      printHuffTree(huffTree[1], prefix + '0')
      printHuffTree(huffTree[2], prefix + '1')

def OnButton():
    exampleData = [(0.124167  , 'e'),   (0.0969225 , 't'),(0.0820011 , 'a'),]
    huffTree = makeHuffTree(exampleData)
    printHuffTree(huffTree)

button = Button(root, text="Press me!", command=OnButton)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can I now make a my GUI to output the results?

Comment: Where are you creating the button?

Comment: the button is not a problem, I can create it, but then I can't connect this button to run the code, after I press it, and then results in GUI.

Comment: @thaking hi I am creating program deflate algo using tkinter? Your code for huffman tree wud b helpful to me.. Cn u plz pass me? Any kind of Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add something like the following in your code:

```
def OnButton():
    exampleData = [(0.124167  , 'e'),   (0.0969225 , 't'),(0.0820011 , 'a'),]
    huffTree = makeHuffTree(exampleData)
    printHuffTree(huffTree)

button = Button(root, text="Press me!", command=OnButton)
button.pack()
```

If by '"print" result's in GUI." you mean you want the results to appear in a window rather than on stdout, you'll need to add something like a text widget and replace all your `print` statements with `<textwidget>.insert` statements/

Comment: Many thanks for this hint, I change my code(see on edit2), but now I don't know how to make windows, which will show my results in GUI. This "printHuffTree(huffTree)" print result's in IDLE.

Comment: @thaking: like I said in my answer, you'll need to create a text widget (eg: `textwidget=Text(root, ...); textwidget.pack(...)` and change your print statements to insert statements. The only way to get a satisfactory result, though, is to take some time to work through a Tkinter tutorial. Just asking for a specific solution to your specific problem will result in an endless cycle of "thanks, but now how do I ...".